# Rewrite/Change custom taxonomy slug

Tags: plugins, custom-taxonomy, permalinks, rewrite-rules, slug

I want this url: =>
**mydomain.com/genre/chant**

to be rewritten as =>
**mydomain.com/chambers/chant**.

I want the users to access **mydomain.com/chambers/chant** instead of **mydomain.com/genre/chant**.

`genre` is a custom taxonomy for custom post type `tracks`. This custom taxonomy is registered in the theme. I want to change its slug from `genre` to `chambers` in my plugin. How do I do it?

I tried the below rewrite url code, but it did not work:

`add_rewrite_rule('^chambers/?','index.php?post_type=tracks&taxonomy=genre','top');`

Answer (score 0):

Try using the below code to overwrite arguments of already registered taxonomies.

```
function wp_modify_taxonomy() {

    // get the arguments of the already-registered taxonomy
    $custom_category_args = get_taxonomy( 'genre' );

    // make changes to the args
    $custom_category_args->rewrite['slug'] = 'chambers';
    $custom_category_args->rewrite['with_front'] = false;

    // re-register the taxonomy
    register_taxonomy( 'genre', 'chambers', (array) $custom_category_args );
}
add_action( 'init', 'wp_modify_taxonomy', 11 );
```